# memory fences in subfunction vs in the same function as the data change

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-fences

Are there differences in thread safety if I place memory fences in sub functions rather than into the function that the data is used.
The bottom example includes both versions. I wonder if there are differences that i am not aware of. Are the functions `A_function` and `B_function` equally threadsafe?.

```
#include<atomic>

using std::atomic;
using std::atomic_thread_fence;
using std::memory_order_acquire;
using std::memory_order_release;

typedef struct 
{
    atomic<int> lock;
    int counter;
}Data;

void A_acquire(atomic<int> * lock);
void A_release(atomic<int> * lock);
void A_function(Data * data);
void B_acquire(atomic<int> * lock);
void B_release(atomic<int> * lock);
void B_function(Data * data);

void A_acquire(atomic<int> * lock)
{
    int ticket = lock->fetch_add(1);
    while (0 != ticket)
    {
        lock->fetch_sub(1);
        ticket = lock->fetch_add(1);
    }
    //DIFFERENCE HERE
}

void A_release(atomic<int> * lock)
{
    //DIFFERENCE HERE
    lock->fetch_sub(1);
}

void A_function(Data * data)
{
    A_acquire(&data->lock);
    atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); //DIFFERENCE HERE
    data->counter += 1;
    atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release); //DIFFERENCE HERE
    A_release(&data->lock);
}

void B_acquire(atomic<int> * lock)
{
    int ticket = lock->fetch_add(1);
    while (0 != ticket)
    {
        lock->fetch_sub(1);
        ticket = lock->fetch_add(1);
    }
    atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); //DIFFERENCE HERE
}

void B_release(atomic<int> * lock)
{
    atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release); //DIFFERENCE HERE
    lock->fetch_sub(1);
}

void B_function(Data * data)
{
    B_acquire(&data->lock);
    //DIFFERENCE HERE
    data->counter += 1;
    //DIFFERENCE HERE
    B_release(&data->lock);
}

int main(void)
{
    Data dat = { 0, 0 };
    A_function(&dat);
    B_function(&dat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Something could happen between the `atomic_thread_fence`s, which would cause a data race.

Comment: @Phantom could my acquire/release functions get reordered if the fences are located in them rather than outside of them or are you pointing out that this would be bad style since the fences are less visible that way?

Comment: Oops, missed the mutex lock, that code should be fine. However, the thread fences are unnecessary because locking and unlocking a mutex already has acquire/release semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is semantically no difference between `A_function` and `B_function`. Memory fence effect is not bounded by the function's body.

Also, as Phantom notes, memory fences in your example are unneccessary: both `fetch_sub()` and `fetch_add()` already have acquire + release semantic.

But with modifications below, release fetch becomes vital:

```
void A_acquire(atomic<int> * lock)
{
    int ticket = lock->exchange(1);
    while (0 != ticket)
    {
        ticket = lock->exchange(1);
    }
    //DIFFERENCE HERE
}

void A_release(atomic<int> * lock)
{
    //DIFFERENCE HERE
    lock->store(0, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```